# Why is modification of array b possible?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

a and b are both array name. why is ++b is permitted while ++a is not.

```
int main(void)
{
int a[3][3] = { 0 };

foo(a);

return 0;
}
void foo(int b[][3])
{
++b;

}
```

Comment: Because `a` is an array, but `b` is not

Answer (score 3):

When you declare an argument such as `int b[][3]`, what the compiler really translates it as is `int (*b)[3]`. That is, `b` is a *pointer* and not an array.

Note that this translation only happens for function arguments, and only for the *first* "dimension".